# Change UILabel Text Color after touch event

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, textcolor

I have a scrollview with some `UILabel`s, and I want to change the `UILabel` text color after tabbing on the label.

I created the `UILabel` in a loop, I am trying to figure out how I can refer back to the exact `UILabel` and how to make them change text color after touch.

```
-(void)barbuttondisplay{
UIScrollView * leftNaviNaviButtonView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,delegate.windowWidth, 44)];
[leftNaviNaviButtonView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[newsgetcategoryDict objectForKey:@"category"]count]*101, 0)];
leftNaviNaviButtonView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[leftNaviNaviButtonView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[leftNaviNaviButtonView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
leftNaviNaviButtonView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;

for(int i=0;i<[[newsgetcategoryDict objectForKey:@"category"]count];i++)
{
    UILabel * contentLable = [[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
    [contentLable setFrame:CGRectMake((i*100)+10,5,80,30)];

    [contentLable setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:appFontRegular size:16]];
    [contentLable setText:[[[newsgetcategoryDict objectForKey:@"category"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"category_name"]];
    if(catid == [[[newsgetcategoryDict objectForKey:@"category"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"category_id"])
    {
        [contentLable setTextColor:AppThemeColor];
    }else{
        [contentLable setTextColor:headercolor];
    }
    //[contentLable setTextColor:headercolor];
    [contentLable setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [contentLable setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [contentLable setTag:i];
    [leftNaviNaviButtonView addSubview:contentLable];
    [contentLable setNumberOfLines:2];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *textTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotocategorypage:)];
    [contentLable addGestureRecognizer:textTap];

}


[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer,[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftNaviNaviButtonView]autorelease], nil]];
[leftNaviNaviButtonView release];
}

-(void)gotocategorypage:(UIGestureRecognizer*) sender
{

int tag =(int)(UIGestureRecognizer*)[sender.view tag];

if(![catid isEqualToString:[[[newsgetcategoryDict objectForKey:@"category"] objectAtIndex:tag] objectForKey:@"category_id"]])
{
    catid = [[[newsgetcategoryDict objectForKey:@"category"] objectAtIndex:tag] objectForKey:@"category_id"];


}else{
    catid = @"";

}
```

So after tabbing on the `UILabel`, "catid" is set, but I think since the label is already created so it won't change its color?

Comment: this line will change label text color, paste it in your GestureHandle method : ((UILabel *)sender.view).textColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: Did you try moving `contentLable setTextColor:` to `gotocategorypage` ?

Comment: ((UILabel *)sender.view).textColor = [UIColor redColor]; this actually worked!! Thanks a lot.